# ESP-12E circuit problem

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, esp8266

I am trying to use an ESP-12E module to detect a voltage & drive a MOSFET and LED.

My schematic is attached.

I am having trouble getting this on and after checking it several times, I can't understand what am I doing that is wrong. The schematic is [here](https://easyupload.io/ij56m5).  This is my Arduino code:

(Added Later) :One thing I learnt is that I have not pulled down GPIO15 to ground, is that what is preventing my ESP from booting normally?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


#define MOSFET 2
#define SWITCH 0
#define LED 5
#define DEBUG True



void setup() {

  pinMode(SWITCH, INPUT);     
  pinMode(MOSFET, OUTPUT);     
  
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  
  
  digitalWrite(MOSFET, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
 

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
#endif

  
  }

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MOSFET, HIGH);
  delay(1000);                       
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MOSFET, LOW);
  delay(1000);        
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is it doing that is wrong?  What does it do that it shouldn't?  What does it not do that it should?

Comment: It is not booting.

Comment: That's a start.  That belongs in your question.  How do you know it isn't booting?

Comment: I just learnt that GPIO15 needs to be pulled down for normal operation, I have missed that in my circuit & pcb. May be that is the only problem.

Comment: I checked the PCB and the voltages are right where they should be, the supply is also solid. Code is also working in nodeMCU. But my ESP12 is not booting.

Comment: What about the other pins? Have you checked how they must be connected to boot?

Comment: https://desire.giesecke.tk/index.php/2018/07/06/reserved-gpios/

Comment: @Justme yes I checked, I think the issue most probably is that I have not pulled down GPIO15 and left it floating. I think I will also avoid using GPIOs 0 (pulled high), 2 (left floating) and 15 (pulled down).

Answer (score 1):

**ESP8266 (ESP-12) pins and io overview:**

---

**UART**

io3 RX0

io1 TX0

---

**boot config pins** with pullup or pulldown on board

io0 PULLUP (LOW for boot to flashing mode)

io2 TX1 PULLUP (UART1 TX. no RX for UART1)

io15 PULLDOWN (SS pin if esp8266 is SPI slave); TX if UART is swapped

---

**untroubled GPIOs** with optional function for I2C or SPI bus:

io5 default pin for I2C SCL in Arduino Wire library

io4 default pin for I2C SCA in Arduino Wire library

io14 SPI CLK

io12 SPI MISO

io13 SPI MOSI; RX if UART is swaped

---

**RTC pin** for timed deep sleep wake-up (if connected to reset pin)

io16 - optional internal pulldown, internal pullup not available

---

**not useable**: pins io 6 to io 11 connect QIO SPI flash memory
(in a very special setup the SPI bus can be used with other SPI device)
(in other very special setup the QIO pins can be used as gpio)

*note: most digital IO start with internal pull-up on*

Answer (score 0):

Grounded GPIO15 and now it works.